# Can not force stop python script using ctrl + C

Tags: python, datetime, while-loop

Normally to force stop python script that are running, we normal just press Ctrl + C (in Interactive console). In this case, it does not stop, when I press Ctrl + C. Here is my code for this situation:

```
import datetime  
from datetime import timedelta  
x = datetime.datetime.now()
print(x)
i=0
while (datetime.datetime.now()<x + timedelta(seconds=20) ):
    print(i)
    i=i+1
```

I want it to force it to stop before the 20seconds is reached.

Please help explain why this happened and help find a solution to this.

Comment: What *exactly* do you mean by "before the 20seconds is reached" ?

Comment: I can't reproduce this.  Ctrl-C works fine for me.

Comment: Add a short `time.sleep()` to the loop.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

It's just you. It accepted the KeyboardInterrupt for me.

[image: screenshot of KeyboardInterrupt halting execution of program]